# what is the File Path of the SDCARD from Emulator programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

all already push some files to the emulator .iso for the sdcard for the emulator,

my problem is how to load all the video because i dont know the correct filepath
of the videoes from the folder of the sdcard from the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

```
File primaryExtSd=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

That is path to SD card root directory